# Xamarin. listview click on button inside list item

Tags: android-listview, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am creating a listview which has many elements and one element is expand button. When I click on expand button i want to show some more button which are hidden with each list item. ( i.e each list item has separate buttons)

I know how to add click event with button inside listview item

in my custom adapter ..

```
getView(){

    var expandBtn = findViewById(_)..

    expandBtn.click += (sender,e)=>{
       //  this block should do show hide of my other buttons.
       //  how to get them here. 
    };    

}
```